# Facebook Graph Api Token not working for Language and Audience bounded posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, setting, audience

I am using Facebook Graph Api v2.8, to fetch all the posts for a page, for which i have admin access. Using this account i created the Extended Access token, to fetch data for analysis.

Recently we have faced issues, to download all the posts from the page.
On further inspection we saw that Short Lived Tokens fetches all the post irrespective of the Language and Audience settings for each post.

While the API to fetch posts using the extended access token does not fetch posts with post settings: 
                      *"Visible to Language: Arabic
                      News Feed audience: Language: Arabic"*

But,works fine for:
                     *"Visible to: Language: English(US) or English(UK)
                     News Feed Audience: Language: English(US) or English(UK)"*

API Call:

*URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/" + id + "?fields=posts.limit(100){likes.limit(0).summary(true),shares,message,created_time,link,type,comments.limit(0).summary(true),reactions.limit(0).summary(true)}&access_token=****"*

Error: 400 Bad request

In short what should be the API call/Access token settings to fetch all posts irrespective of Audience and Language settings???

What am i doing wrong?
Any sort of directions/input also to solve this is highly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Sounds like you are using an app access token. You need to use a page access token for the page, or a user token for a user that is allowed to see those posts.

Comment: i did assume that in the beginning, and have tried it with user access token and page token too. it works fine for the short lived tokens but the extended tokens only fetch   "Visible to: Language: English(US) or English(UK) News Feed Audience: Language: English(US) or English(UK)" posts

Comment: If you get a 400 status code, that should be accompanied by a response body that contains a readable error message - go check.

Comment: any one with any solution to this????